# Trouble getting MAMP to work with PDO-MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, doctrine, pdo, mamp

Problem: Doctrine test application isn't working because of driver issue.

Setup: Mac OS X 10.5.7 (not server), MAMP 1.7.2, Doctrine 2.2.1, PHP 5.2.6

I am following the doctrine [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/getting-started) to try to set up a development environment on my local machine. The output of running the page from the web (through MAMP) shows an empty screen (I am assuming because errors are not shown through MAMP). If I run the page on my test environment (Debian Lenny) everything works perfectly and there is output on the screen.

I have been trying to figure it out for hours and I haven't been able to. Any insight is appreciated.

Here is the output when run from the command line.

```
justingiboney$ php test.php

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/doctrine_test_site/bootstrap.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/doctrine_test_site/bootstrap.php(16): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=fa...', '****', '****')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/doctrine_test_site/test.php(4): require_once('/Applications/M...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/doctrine_test_site/bootstrap.php on line 16
```

Here is test.php

```
<?php
// test.php

 require_once('bootstrap.php');

 $conn->export->createTable('test', array('name' => array('type' => 'string')));
 $conn->execute('INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (?)', array('jwage'));

 $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
 $stmt->execute();
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
 print_r($results);

?>
```

Here is bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php

/**
* Bootstrap Doctrine.php, register autoloader specify
* configuration attributes and load models.
*/
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=****;host=127.0.0.1:8889';
$user = '****';
$password = '****';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);
$conn->setOption('****', $user);
$conn->setOption('****', $password);

?>
```

If I run phpinfo() through the MAMP page I see a few lines that make it look like PDO-MySQL is installed

```
--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library

PDO drivers | sqlite2, sqlite, pgsql, mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version    5.0.41
```

Comment: To facilitate detection of errors, you can set error_reporting to E_ALL, and display_errors to On, in the php.ini file (where this file is on your system should be indicated near the top of phpinfo()'s output) ; maybe there is an error you just don't see.

Comment: Okay that showed me that it was having trouble connecting to mysql. So I switched the MAMP port back to 3306 and took out the 8889 in my code and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, this type of question is better suited for ServerFault.com, a sister site of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Quinn your so smart... i don't know where I would be without you

Comment: @Justin Giboney > you're welcome :-)

Answer (score -1):

It does not seem like the PDO module is installed properly in your MAMP configuration. when you run phpinfo() you should have a block called PDO which defines which PDO drivers that are enabled.

My phpinfo page have a block like this:

```
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql
```

You should double check to see that you MAMP installation have all the required library files available.

Comment: sorry missed that line:
From phpinfo() PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version 5.0.41

Comment: and how would I check to see if it has all the required libraries? Where would I look, and what would I look for?